# What should I do when my question is specious but has a good answer?

Tags: discussion

I asked a [question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/22265/how-can-i-get-the-same-usb-hdd-speeds-in-rasbpian-as-in-raspbmc) asking how to get equivalent behaviour in Raspbian and Raspbmc. I received what appears to be an interesting answer from Sam Nazarko, the developer of Raspbmc (although I couldn't actually verify his suggestions).

However, since then, I've discovered that the differences I experienced were not due to distributions, but Raspberry Pi hardware revisions. What should I do about the question? I don't want to delete it, because I think there is potentially interesting information in the answer. Should I just close it?

Comment: Have you considered writing up the info you found about the hardware revisions as an answer.

Comment: @SteveRobillard Yes, but then it wouldn't answer the question as stated. I thought of changing the question (and title), but then Sam Nazarko's answer would not make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is the question that is flawed and not the answer, you should probably delete the question. As good as Sam's answer was if it no longer applies you should probably delete the question. Ask yourself this since the question was flawed (non identical hardware) who would find  this question via search? Why would they be searching for this.

Comment: Good point. My primary concern with deleting it was that his answer would be forever lost. Do you think that instead of deleting the question, I could just close it (i.e. it's still publicly accessible), then open a new question that I can answer with my own findings?

Comment: Closing requires a reason and none of them apply. Second nothing on the internet is ever lost Google cache likely already contains the page. Leaving an invalid question to maintain answer is the greater of the two evils here. You should delete the question.

Comment: I'm not sure that Google holds caches for deleted pages, but I've deleted the question anyway. The new question is [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/22357/why-is-there-a-difference-in-usb-hdd-speed-in-my-two-raspberry-pis).

Comment: Ha, and having said that… "Sorry, this question has answers and cannot be deleted; flag it for moderator attention instead." (I've flagged it.)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it would be best to post your original question and add your own answer for a hardware issue, and then edit your existing question to what you believe the correct question for his answer is, and then link to your "new" question saying "original question" or similar

Comment: I'm slightly wary of doing this, because of the specious nature of my original question. Since my presumptions were totally off-target, I would be in no position to accept any answer to the original question.